# Can I build a browser (chrome, firefox, etc.) extension with Nuxt JS? If so, then how?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, browser-extension

I want to build a fully functional chrome extension.
The extension will have:

- Popup Window
- Content Injection
- Custom NewTab Action
- Options/Settings Page

I want to build this with Nuxt 3. But, I can't.

I've created an small chrome extension with core JavaScript.
But, I don't understand how to create with Nuxt 3.
Where to put manifest.json!
How to configure popup, etc.

Comment: I am not sure about Nuxt3 (I just lost the link/way to do so) but you could do so with Vitesse: https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-webext Feel also free to ask in the community (we have a call this evening on Nuxt's Discord).